# How does DRM enforcement work (across different platforms)?

Tags: drm, pdf

I would like to know how Android, Windows, Linux, and OS X deal with DRM (Digital Rights Management) e-pub, pdf, and mp3 files. Basically, if I download a DRM file to my device (perhaps one that has an expiry date or forbids copying of the file), can't anyone write a custom (despite illegal in most countries, or perhaps even one for personal use written by a coder who knows enough about DRM)  program to ignore the DRM portions of the file and turn it into a regular non-DRM file?

Answer (score 2):

As long as any program capable of reading the DRM protected file is working on your computer, experts can analyze it and write a program that circumvents DRM for that file for an indefinite amount of time.

There are DRM systems in which the key to decrypt the content is calculated just-in-time by a server. If you didn't save the key before expiration, you likely can't access this file with any software after expiration.

Comment: Thanks. Is this how DRM in e-pub and pdf files from sites like Google Play works? Thanks.